# Dynamically append foreach statements to c# code

Tags: c#, foreach

I'm busy on a c# project where I have a List{1,2,3}. I want to form all possible matches between the elements of the List object. That would be easy to do by using 3 foreach loops.

```
foreach(int one in list)
{
     foreach(int two in list)
     {
           foreach(int three in list)
           {
                  // ...
            }}}
```

But if I don't know the amount of elements in the list object : how can I do all matches by using foreach loops?So if there are 6 elements in the list, then there should be 6 underlying foreach loops...
(I don't want to use if statements as seen as it uses too much space) 
And if I use foreach loops, how can I dynamically change the name of the variable used in the foreach loop? (Can you say :

```
     String "number"+i = new String("..."); //where i = number (int)
```

EDIT :

The output should be :

```
 1,1,1
 1,2,1
 1,2,2
 1,2,3
 1,3,1
 1,3,2
 1,3,3
 ...
```

Comment: try Recursion I am not able to understand your requirement

Comment: "form all possible matches" - what do you mean by that? Can you give an example? Sounds a bit like an [X-Y Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: Give some example on Matching the elements in the List.

Comment: do you want cartesian product?

Comment: Yes recursion is what you need

Comment: see my edit for an example of the preferred output

Comment: @user2698666 Do you want to print the variables in the order 'one,two,three'? Are you sure the output pattern is right?

Comment: I just want to simulate multiple foreach loops : then I can apply some other code... so if I have 3 elements in a list, then 3 foreach loops of that list will be executed and then I can perform my extra code on it. If I have 600 items in the list then it would be chaotic. So I need a way of dynamically adding the required amount of foreach loops and then executing my additional code

Answer (score 1):

From your definition i guess you need a power set. Example taken from [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set#C.23)

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPowerSet<T>(List<T> list)
{
        return from m in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << list.Count)
               select
                   from i in Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count)
                   where (m & (1 << i)) != 0
                   select list[i];
}

private void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        List<int> temp = new List<int>() { 1,2,3};

        List<IEnumerable<int>> ab = GetPowerSet(temp).ToList();
        Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                                 ab.Select(subset =>
                                 string.Join(",", subset.Select(clr => clr.ToString()).ToArray())).ToArray()));
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1
2
1,2
3
1,3
2,3
1,2,3
```

Comment: and when the output must contain all 3 items in 1 output line? (see my edit on the question)

Answer (score 0):

another approach is to get the current item and the rest. Then you can do your thing also

```
foreach (var one in ItemList)
{
  var currentItem = one;
  var otherItems = ItemList.Except(currentItem);

  // Now you can do all sort off things
}
```

Comment: Except is a set operation and does a kind of distinct. 1, 1, 1 except 1 is **not** 1, 1. [More info](http://www.siepman.nl/blog/post/2013/08/19/Except-intersect-and-union-without-distinct.aspx).