# programmatic defined # foreach loops c#

Tags: c#, foreach, nested

Here are two examples :

I have an array with 3 items : Universe, planet and Continent
I want to use a foreach loop like this :

```
  foreach(var universe in Universe)
  {
       foreach(var planet in Planet)
       {
             foreach(var continent in Continent)
             { 
                 // here comes my code
              } } }
```

In this case the array contains 3 elements and therefore I need 3 foreach statements.

Now lets say that I add 2 extra items to the array (Country and State)
There would have to be 5 foreach loops.

But what if the array contains 600 items  : then I would need to write 600 foreach statements...

So how can this be programatically solved?

- Dynamic code addition?
- Recursive codes (I have no experience with them)
- ...

Comment: If `Universe`, `Earth` and `Continent` are collections why are they singular terms? Why would an Earth have multiple earths? And a continent can't really have multiple continents: it defies the definition of continent a bit.

Comment: ok - I just chose that as an example, but lets say planet?

Comment: It's still singular. Are each of these things collections, or what? Please give a concrete example and explanation.

Comment: Your question is not clear, you may want to explain what are you trying to achieve, Array is an object that contains collection of objects, for example A basket is an array, it may contain 10 apples, 6 oranges, and 4 banana.

Comment: This question looks strangely similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327942/dynamically-append-foreach-statements-to-c-sharp-code ... and again, you ask for a solution for Y when you should ask for a solution for X instead ([XYProblem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)).

Comment: by the question you posted I think you are probably searching for a solution for some very simple problem that was made incredible complex by bad design decision and/or low understanding of the language

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/10629938/1336590 will help.

Comment: So you want 600 variables? You know that if each collection is of 2 elements, the total number of cycles is 2^600? It's so much big that I don't even know how much big it's!

Comment: @xanatos - If it is like in the other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327942/dynamically-append-foreach-statements-to-c-sharp-code) it's even 600!

Comment: Eric Lippert got the answer in his blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx Your code should be CarthesianProduct(new [] { Universe, Planet, Continent}).Select(x => string.Join(",", x)).ToList()

Answer (score 1):

If you have one array with three items in it, then in order to enumerate through the items you should only need one foreach loop.

```
List<Object> items = new List<Object> { Universe, Earth, Continent };
foreach (var item in items) { ... }
```

You would only need to write additional nested foreach loops if the objects contained by the outer array each themselves implemented `IEnumerable`, and you needed to enumerate these as well. Without seeing the problem that you are trying to solve, it is hard to make a recommendation. But I think that the assumption that you need to have nested `foreach` structures is incorrect.